# connect: Network is unreachable

Tags: networking

I was writing software which uses UNIX sockets and suddenly my internet stopped working even after restarting my laptop.

Symptoms:

- ping 8.8.8.8 returns: "Connect: Network is unreachable"
- ip route list: returns nothing
- I can see I am connected to my home router but am unable to browse the internet
- this is what I get wheb typing ifconfig: https://imgur.com/a/lX2RIWB

What is the issue and how can I solve this? I tried many things I found online but nothing worked

Comment: "tried many things I found online" ... like what? The problem is either your ISP, your router, or your Ubuntu system - what have you done to rule out each possibility? And what were the results? You were mucking with Sockets...which sockets exactly? Is your software still active?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem

This works for me in 20.04LTS with a an old dell laptop

sudo service network-manager restart

sync

...(keep executing sync until there is no delay when you hit return)

sync

ping 192.168.1.8   -c3