# Network is unreachable / Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, ethernet

I've been using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (x64) via VMWare (my main OS is Windows 10) for the last month.
Recently when I try to ping ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com) for example) I get

`ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I followed some answers on different posts about this and yesterday, when I added the next line:
`nameserver 8.8.8.8` to my `/etc/resolv.conf` it fixed it for me.

Today, after I rebooted the machine this problem happening again, but this time adding the `nameserver 8.8.8.8` didn't work, and when I try to `ping 8.8.8.8` I get:

`ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

I tried doing the proposed answers there: [Temporary failure in name resolution continuously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393818/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-continuously), [connect: Network is unreachable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090706/connect-network-is-unreachable)
but that didn't help neither.

Additional info: on my main OS (Windows 10 x64) everything is working completely fine.

Now, when I look through my host it seems that the vmnet1 & 8 have no dhcp enabled, but I can't figure out how to enable it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Temporary failure in name resolution is typically an ISP issue if it is all sites. Have you contacted them?

Comment: @David My main OS is windows and everything works just fine in it

Comment: I do not see that mentioned in the question. Please update the question and put in this important info.

Comment: @David fixed that now. thought that when I say it's through VM its clear

Answer (score 1):

In my case, though it's about wsl windows(ubuntu v20), I fixed the problem in the following step.

1. Check your IP in Ethernet by powershell by `powershell> ipconfig`.
2. Modify your `/etc/resolv.conf` about the line `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` based on 1st step.
3. Restart wsl(`powershell > wsl --shutdown`); In your case, it's VMWare.